# Post order traversal to calculate the path sum in a binary tree

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to solve the problem [Path Sum - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/path-sum).

> 112. Path Sum
>
> Given a binary tree and a sum, determine if the tree has a root-to-leaf path such that adding up all the values along the path equals the given sum.
>
> **Note:** A leaf is a node with no children.
>
> **Example:**
>
> Given the below binary tree and `sum = 22`,
>
> ```
>       5
>      / \
>     4   8
>    /   / \
>   11  13  4
>  /  \      \
> 7    2      1
> ```
>
> return true, as there exist a root-to-leaf path `5->4->11->2` which sum is 22.

I plan to solve it with an intuitive post order traversal.

```py
# Definition for a binary tree node.
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Solution:
    def hasPathSum(self, root: TreeNode, sum: int) -> bool:

    def postorder(self, root):
        if not root: return 
        self.postorder(root.left)
        self.postorder(root.right)
        loc_sum = loc_sum + self.postorder(root.val)
```

Then I have no idea how I could continue. Could you please give some hints?

Comment: Hint: If a node has value `v` and must have a path that sums to `N`, then at least one of its child nodes must have a path that sums to `N - v`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @meowgoesthedog pointed out, you can solve this problem using recursion. In the following example I go down the tree while descreasing the required sum with the current value. I keep doing this as long as there is a left or right node (if both are present, it checks for both of them). If no left and no right element are found (which means you hit a leaf) I just check whether or not the remaining required sum is equal to the current value. You can do this with just your `hasPathSum(,root,sum):` function, but using a separate `postOrder` function would be possible as well.

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Solution:
    def hasPathSum(self, root: TreeNode, sum: int) -> bool:
        if root.left: 
           if return self.hasPathSum(root.left, sum-root.val): return True
        if root.right:
           if return self.hasPathSum(root.right, sum-root.val): return True
        else: return root.val == sum
```

Comment: I don't think this is valid solution- consider case where the root has the value of the sum and have children - your function will return true while it shouldn't

Comment: why it fails for case [], [1 2]

Comment: @dWinder you are completely right I overlooked that case. I fixed it in the updated version

Comment: Still no good - what if root has left node but answer path is in right? (Your code will return false as it never check right...) - you should check both sides and return true only if recursion was true. At last check check also if leaf.